# Understanding Gradle's Kotlin DSL in terms of "plain Kotlin"

Tags: kotlin, gradle

**tldr: I don't see how Gradle's Kotlin DSL for defining tasks is valid Kotlin and I need references to official Kotlin docs that can explain it**

## The longer version

I am reading the docs of OpenAPI's Gradle Generator to try and understand the API and came across [this bit in the docs](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin/README.adoc#tasks):

```
// Define a task for validating one specification
task validateGoodSpec(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.ValidateTask) {
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/petstore-v3.0.yaml")
}
```

Beside the point that this does not like [how you register tasks in the official Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html), this almost looks like a normal function definition (if one replaced `task` with `fun), but I do not remember coming across syntax like this in any "normal" Kotlin code. I know this is the Gradle DSL, but I still thought it was supposed to be valid Kotlin. Is this assumption wrong?

Stuffing the example into IntelliJ, it could not resolve this code to the right overloaded signature of the `task` function, which was a bit strange ...:
[image: failing]
[image: explanation from intellij]

I then [tried asking ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/share/0c5847b4-5263-43e7-b325-80fc8d4e8e6d) to "translate" the Kotlin code to plain Java ... I think it was  hallucinating, as it added an extra `Class<T>` argument out of nowhere, but after some cleanup, I think the result should be something like this

```
task<ValidateTask>("validateGoodSpec") {
    outputs.upToDateWhen {
        false;
    }
    // etc ....
}
```

This, at least, is code I understand how works and fits an existing function signature:

```
public open fun task(name: kotlin.String, configureAction: org.gradle.api.Action<in org.gradle.api.Task>): org.gradle.api.Task`
```

Still, the I have no idea how the Kotlin compiler magically can turn `task validateGoodSpec(someAction)` into `task("validateGoodSpec", someAction)`!

Comment: That first code block looks like the Groovy DSL, not the Kotlin DSL.

Comment: All the gradle code in that link seems to be Groovy, not Kotlin.

Comment: Aha, that did not even cross my mind, which I guess it should have ... Good call. One could wonder why the docs makes no mention of this.

Comment: You could post that as the answer, if you would like the point. At least I got a resolution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments already pointed out, the code you're showing isn't Kotlin DSL, it's Gradle's Groovy DSL. So, yes, this syntax is not valid Kotlin, and there is no real mystery :)

That being said, there are weird things going on even in Kotlin DSL sometimes. The Kotlin code of Gradle build scripts is compiled with some twists. For instance, the property assignment syntax using `=` instead of `.set(...)` in Gradle 8.2 relies on a compiler plugin (see [their blog post](https://blog.gradle.org/simpler-kotlin-dsl-property-assignment)). So watch out for those!